# Slicing shapefile by negative coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, coordinates, ogr, ogr2ogr

I have a shapefile that contains data for both sides of the Greenwich meridian.

According to `ogrinfo`, this shapefile has the extents of `(-9.298157, 35.265607) - (4.327108, 45.046054)`. I want to copy all data in the bounding box `(42.5, -0.5) - (43.5, 1)`. But using `ogr2ogr`, I got an empty shapefile (it had just 100 bytes …)! I used the following command:

```sh
ogr2ogr -progress -spat 42.5 -0.5 43.5 1 outfile.shp infile.shp
```

If `ogr2ogr` does not understand negative coordinates, then how do I get that data out of that shapefile?

Comment: Perhaps there really is no data inside this small area even though the extent is greater?

Comment: You probably have your coordinates in the wrong order. ogrinfo says "-9.298157, 35.265607" etc but you pass "42.5, -0.5" etc... Try `-spat -0.5 42.5 1 43.5`

Comment: @user2856 OMG I'm dumb - that did the trick !

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @user2856, `ogr2ogr` *does* understand negative coordinates - I only specified the coordinates in the wrong order. The correct and working command is:

```sh
ogr2ogr -progress -spat -0.5 42.5 1 43.5 outfile.shp infile.shp
```